# Stieltjes inversion formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, spectral-theory

Let $[a,b] \subset \rho(T)$ and $T$ be a self-adjoint operator

then I want to show that $0=\frac{1}{\pi} \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \lim_{\delta \downarrow 0} \int_{a+\delta}^{b+\delta} Im(\langle (T-s-i\varepsilon)^{-1}x,x \rangle ds$

My idea is that for small $\delta$ we have $[a+\delta , b+\delta] \subset \rho(T)$ and therefore $(T-s)^{-1}$ exists and $\langle (T-s)^{-1}x,x \rangle $ is purely real, as this operator is then also self-adjoint, but I don't quite see how to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
                 (x,(T-\lambda I)x) \in\mathbb{R},\;\;\; x \in \mathcal{D}(T).
$$
Therefore, if $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\cap\rho(T)$, you can set $x = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}y$ for any $y \in X$ in order to obtain
$$
              ((T-\lambda I)^{-1}y,y) \in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: what I meant about making rigorous is the limit $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: The function $\lambda\mapsto ((T-\lambda)^{-1}y,y)$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $[a-\gamma,b+\gamma]$ for some $\gamma > 0$ and is real-valued on this interval. The limits is easy to take knowing that.

Comment: how do we know that it is holomorphic?

Comment: The resolvent is holomorphic on the resolvent set $\rho(T)$. Holomorphic is overkill here; continuity is more than enough.